# Simple way to make an igraph graph have movable nodes in a Shiny App?

Tags: r, shiny, igraph

Suppose I make an igraph graph G. Is there a simple way to plot G and make the nodes movable by click and drag in a shiny application? I don't want the bouncing graphs, just simple physics.

Answer (score -1):

Use the visNetwork library and the command visIgraph(G).